# ReactJS - setState não funciona com o primeiro Valor no onClick

Tags: react, react-hooks, react-dom

Bom di!

Estou utilizando o React na versão 16.11.0 e toda vez que eu utilizo o **setState** utilizando função, o primeiro valor que eu seto, ele sempre vem em branco.

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
  //Declaração do State
  const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

  //Criação do componente botão
  export default function Button({ children, ...rest }) {
    return (
      <Botao type="button" {...rest}>
        {children}
      </Botao>
    );
  }


  //Chamada do Componente botão e com função onClick
  <Botao
  value={BotoesPassword[0]}
  onClick={event => {
    setSenha(event.target.value);
    console.log(senha);
  }}
  >
```

Print de como aparece no console( A primeira linha é no **1** Click e a segunda no **2** Click)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque os updates dos valores do estado do componente não acontecem imediatamente após o `setState` ser executado - o valor só muda na ocasião do próximo `render`. Você pode verificar isso usando um effect como:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(senha);
}, [senha])
```

Esse effect vai ser executado uma vez, quando o seu componente terminar de montar, e uma vez subsequentemente a cada vez que `senha` mudar.